# Halcon - get lowest pixel of a region along a line

Tags: line, intersection, region, halcon

I have a random region, and would need the coordinates in the world plane of the intersection between the region and the center of the image, with the highest y coordinate.

this is what I have so far:

```
fill_up(SelectedRegions, RegionFillUp)
get_image_size(Image, w,h)
gen_region_line(RegionLine,0,w/2,h,w/2)
disp_line (3600, 0, w/2, h, w/2)
intersection (RegionFillUp, RegionLine, RegionIntersection)
```

[image]

***EDIT**

I've made some progress and have now all the intersections. But cannot figure out how to get the last entry of the array if the array is bigger than one...

```
gen_contour_region_xld (RegionFillUp, Contours, 'border')
get_image_size(Image, w,h)
gen_contour_polygon_xld (Line1,[0,h],[w/2,w/2])
intersection_line_contour_xld(Contours,0,w/2,h,w/2,rowcoords, columncoords, isOverlapping)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it this way:

```
fill_up(SelectedRegions, RegionFillUp)
gen_contour_region_xld (RegionFillUp, Contours, 'border')
get_image_size(Image, w,h)
intersection_line_contour_xld(Contours,0,w/2,h,w/2,rowcoords, columncoords, isOverlapping)
disp_cross (3600, rowcoords, columncoords, 6, 0)
tuple_length (rowcoords,Length)
Position := 0
if (Length > 0) 
    Position := rowcoords[Length-1]
endif

image_points_to_world_plane (CamParam, Pose, Position, w/2, 1, X1, Y1)
```